# Do you know how to get the module object after lazyretry?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

Currently, I have created a lazy.ts function that refreshes when a chunk error occurs after lazyretry. This function receives modules and name, and imports the name of the modules. The caller is lazyImport("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min"). But a problem occurred. The module is pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min. Modules such as react-datepicker can be used as components, but pdfjs will only use objects within the module. So, if you console.log(Pdf) after const Pdf = lazyImport("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min"), you get {$$typeof: Symbol(react.lazy), _payload: {… }, _init: ƒ} This is the output. The output I want is Promise {}

```
lazy.ts

import { ComponentType, lazy } from "react";

type LazyComponent = ComponentType<any> | any;

interface LazyModules {
  [moduleName: string]: () => Promise<{ default: LazyComponent }>;
}

export const lazyLoad =
  (modules: LazyModules): ((name: string) => LazyComponent) =>
  (name: string): LazyComponent =>
    lazy(async () => {
      console.log(name);
      const storageKey = "lazy-refreshed";
      const allRefreshedStatus =
        JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey)!) ?? {};

      const hasRefreshed = allRefreshedStatus[name] ?? false;

      try {
        const module = await modules[name]();
        const component = module.default;
        console.log(component);

        allRefreshedStatus[name] = false;
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(
          storageKey,
          JSON.stringify(allRefreshedStatus)
        );

        if (component === undefined) {
          allRefreshedStatus[name] = true;
          window.sessionStorage.setItem(
            storageKey,
            JSON.stringify(allRefreshedStatus)
          );
          return window.location.reload();
        }

        return component;
      } catch (error) {
        if (!hasRefreshed) {
          allRefreshedStatus[name] = true;
          window.sessionStorage.setItem(
            storageKey,
            JSON.stringify(allRefreshedStatus)
          );
          return window.location.reload();
        }

        throw error;
      }
    });

module.ts

import { lazyLoad } from "./lazy/lazy";

// module.ts
export const modules = {
  "react-datepicker": async () => {
    const module = await import("react-datepicker");
    return { default: module };
  },

  "pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.entry": async () => {
    const module = await import("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.entry");
    const res = await module.pdfjsWorker;
    return { default: res };
  },

  "pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min": async () => {
    const module = await import("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min");
    return module; // Return the entire module, not just workerSrc
  },
};

export const lazyImport = lazyLoad(modules);

App.tsx

const b = lazyImport("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min");
```

```
lazy.ts

import { ComponentType, lazy } from "react";

type LazyComponent = ComponentType<any> | any;

interface LazyModules {
  [moduleName: string]: () => Promise<{ default: LazyComponent }>;
}

export const lazyLoad =
  (modules: LazyModules): ((name: string) => LazyComponent) =>
  (name: string): LazyComponent =>
    lazy(async () => {
      console.log(name);
      const storageKey = "lazy-refreshed";
      const allRefreshedStatus =
        JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey)!) ?? {};

      const hasRefreshed = allRefreshedStatus[name] ?? false;

      try {
        const module = await modules[name]();
        const component = module.default;
        console.log(component);

        allRefreshedStatus[name] = false;
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(
          storageKey,
          JSON.stringify(allRefreshedStatus)
        );

        if (component === undefined) {
          allRefreshedStatus[name] = true;
          window.sessionStorage.setItem(
            storageKey,
            JSON.stringify(allRefreshedStatus)
          );
          return window.location.reload();
        }

        return component;
      } catch (error) {
        if (!hasRefreshed) {
          allRefreshedStatus[name] = true;
          window.sessionStorage.setItem(
            storageKey,
            JSON.stringify(allRefreshedStatus)
          );
          return window.location.reload();
        }

        throw error;
      }
    });

module.ts

import { lazyLoad } from "./lazy/lazy";

// module.ts
export const modules = {
  "react-datepicker": async () => {
    const module = await import("react-datepicker");
    return { default: module };
  },

  "pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.entry": async () => {
    const module = await import("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.entry");
    const res = await module.pdfjsWorker;
    return { default: res };
  },

  "pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min": async () => {
    const module = await import("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min");
    return module; // Return the entire module, not just workerSrc
  },
};

export const lazyImport = lazyLoad(modules);

App.tsx

const b = lazyImport("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min");
```

To prevent chunk loading errors in the pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.min module that dynamically imports, a lazy.ts function is created and refreshed when an error occurs. I don't want to use return(), I just want console.log (an object in pdfjs).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).